# NEXT_AUTH session is not available in POST methods

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I am implementing NextAuth authentication with google as provider. I am also integrating MongoDB as the DB.
I the api endpoints, I am getting session using `getSession`. But the session is coming to be null in the POST methods and works fine with GET requests.

**getDocs.js  **

```
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react"

export default async function handler(req,res){

    if(req.method!="GET") res.status(400).json({status:"error",msg:"Cannot fulfil GET API request"})

    const session = await getSession({req})

        console.log(session)  // session is there. Works fine

    // further code

}
```

**updateDoc.js**

```
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react"
import connectDB from "../../../lib/dbconnect/dbconnect"
import Document from "../../../lib/models/document"
import clientPromise from "@/lib/mongodb"

connectDB()

export default async function handler(req,res){
    
    console.log(req.body)
    
    if(req.method !== "POST")  res.status(400).json({status: "error", msg: "Cannot fulfill GET API request"})

    const session = await getSession({req})
        
        console.log(session)  // session is null. Works fine

    // further code
}
```

**api/auth/[...nextauth].js**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import clientPromise from "../../../lib/mongodb"
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter"

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.NEXTAUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  pages:{
    signIn:'/signin'
  },
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

I found out it works fine for get request because I tried making a get request to the updateDoc.js after removing the if condition to check the method type, and it works fine.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to the question

Use getServerSession instead getSession